# Python3: string in list has different encodings based on how it is accessed

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding

Slightly weird problem here. I have an adjacency list with umlauts in the keys. But it seems the encoding is different in the list and when I iterate over it:

```
adjacency_list = {
    'root':            ['zuw\xc3\xa4chse', 'test2'],
    'zuw\xc3\xa4chse': ['test3', 'test4']
}

print(adjacency_list['root'])
for child in adjacency_list['root']: print(child)
```

Output:

```
['zuw\xc3\xa4chse', 'test2']
zuwächse
test2
```

Why is it 'zuw\xc3\xa4chse' in the list, but if I do `for child in...` *child* is now 'zuwächse'? Why would the encoding be different? I need the encoding to be the same so I can use the value of `child` as a key.

**EDIT**

Thanks to Padraic Cunningham: If you print something, it gets passed through repr. That means the key did not change, just it's visual representation. Turns out this wasn't related to the actual problem I was having, and a total red hering.

Comment: You are are seeing the repr output. i.e the encoded bytes. The encoding has not changed, just the visual representation.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Ah, and that only happens for strings, not for strings in lists? Interesting.

Comment: dicts, lists,tuples etc..  will always give you the repr representation of the object. If you print out each list item you will see the str output like you have with the keys.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham does that only happen on print, because if I do adjacency_list[child] I also get a key error.

Comment: Is the error not for testx? I don't see any of those keys in your dict.

Comment: I found the error, not related to encoding at all, was just a red hering. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also, that string is misencoded. The `\xc3\xa4` should just be `\xe4` since strings in Python 3.x are text, not bytes.